# Angular application displaying nothing with resolver

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I have a resolver - resolving my auth state observable but my web application displays nothing and no errors - any ideas? if I pipe map the value of my auth state observable in my resolver there is a value being emitted.

auth resolver

```
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthResolver implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {
    constructor(private authservice: AuthenticationService) { }

    resolve(): Observable<any> {
        return this.authservice.getAuthState();
    }
}
```

Auth Service

```
 public getAuthState() {
        return this.authenticationState.asObservable();
    }
```

In my app-routes.ts

```
export const ROUTES: Route[] = [
    {
        path: '', component: BaseComponent,resolve: { authState: AuthResolver},  children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'account/create', component: RegisterComponent },
            { path: 'account/login', component: LoginComponent },
        ]
    },

    { path: '404', component: PagenotfoundComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: "/404" }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An observable returned by a resolver needs to complete. Only after that, the page will be loaded. A simple way to achieve that is by using `take(1)`, if you want the newest value of your state observable.

```
resolve(): Observable<any> {
    return this.authservice.getAuthState().pipe(
        take(1)
    );
}
```